# Windows Azure Mobile Services Data Fetching Completed

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, async-await, azure-mobile-services

I can fetch my data using Windows Azure Mobile Services. What I want to do is to put a "Loading..." into my app. Before I can do it, I must know when the data fetching is completed.

The question is "How do I know this?"

Thanks in advance,

#### Some Code

```
private MobileServiceCollection<TodoItem, TodoItem> items;
private IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> itemTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
items = await itemTablosu.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false).ToCollectionAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `ToCollectionAsync` "returns" is when it's done.  Use of `await` builds up a state machine that executes the next line asynchronously on the UI thread when that operation is completed.  You should only need to do something like:

```
items = await itemTablosu.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Complete == false).ToCollectionAsync();

myLoadingControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

This assumes that `ToCollectionAsync()` is called from the UI thread (e.g. a button click, a `Loaded` handler, an `OnNavigatedTo` override, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I don't know why but, I had expected to find a "Completed" event way. Sorry for my inattention.

Comment: yes, they've "appropriated" the "Async" suffix for Task-based patterns.  You could use the `Task` returned from the Async method to do something more complex--but the new patterns don't use events.